# Why is my system architecture i386 on a 64-bit processor?

Tags: debian, 64bit, cpu-architecture

Recently, a small message appeared on my Gmail, notifying me that my google chrome version isn't compatible anymore. So I tried to update my chrome (I didn't take care about my chrome version from quite a while, I'm on version 45.0.2454.99).

So I followed the instructions given by chrome itself and it downloaded `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` for my Debian.

When I tried to install it using:

```
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

It trowed me an error:

```
 dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 (--install):  package architecture (amd64) does not match system
 (i386)
```

Until today I suspected my computer be 64 bits, so I ran `uname -a`

`Linux MyComp 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u4 (2015-09-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

"free" command shows that my SO understands there are 8gigs of ram:

```
            total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:       8071684    5521740    2549944     325624     360696    1918748
```

Added edit:
Still `dpkg --print-architecture`  produces `i386`

What's the deal with my OS? Is or not x64? Why can't upgrade my chrome?

I understand chrome stopped 32 bit support but that shouldn't be a problem for me is it?

Launching `apt-get install google-chrome-stable` gives me:

```
google-chrome-stable is already the newest version.
```

EDIT:

So after following the instructions of doing the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install
```

It got messed up even more.

```
$google-chrome
```

> [1:1:0323/093649:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(114)] Couldn't load
>   libexif. libexif.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory [26967:26967:0323/093649:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(245)]
>   GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "xfce",
>   (10 times)
>
> Aborted

Same when i launch `google-chrome-stable`

Right now im using chronium 45 since i installed it before "properly" installing chrome.

Tried to remove the architecture but:

> dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'amd64' currently in use by
>   the database

Whitch is kinda spected but not desirable as well.

Result:

Well, it ended up on a full reinstal, chrome is not the only aplication that gave me problems and since this seemed a synthom of some kind of wrong/bad installation, i decided to just take the time to do it from 0, keeping some files on /home/backupuser and formatting root.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What does `dpkg --print-architecture` produce?

Comment: looks like your system is reporting its cpu as i368 (I believe Intel) and your downloaded chrome package is for amd64.

Comment: @StephenKitt it produces i386, if its x32 why uname says amd64? Is a config issue on dpgk then? (Im not much into linux/debian etc)

Comment: @MelBurslan yes i did, since chrome dropped suport for x32. But i though my comp is amd64, as "uname -a" and "free" seems to report

Comment: @LeoArmentano: `dpkg` begs to differ I presume. is this a VM guest or installed directly on the hardware. If VM, I' suggest creating a fresh instance and testing it, but if on H/W, it might be little tricky to repartition your disk to install a clone copy.

Comment: You can run a 32-bit user-space with a 64-bit kernel, which is what you have: `i386` packages with an `amd64` kernel.

Comment: @MelBurslan `dpkg --print-architecture` reports `dpkg`'s architecture, it doesn't actually check the installed processor (or VM configuration or whatever). It is actually possible to install and run an `armhf` `dpkg` for instance on an Intel CPU...

Comment: @StephenKitt: thank you for that info. I was not aware of it

Comment: It's bettter to use chromium (itself project) instead of forked project(Chrome). Chrome has been manipulated by google. But when you use chromium via debian repo or other repo , You discard google's policies.

Answer (score 13):

Your system has a 64-bit kernel with 32-bit userspace, which is perfectly valid. Since Chrome is no longer updated for 32-bit systems, you need to enable support for 64-bit userspace; on Debian this is as easy as

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture amd64
sudo apt-get update
```

Then you should be able to install the Chrome package, presumably with errors since you won't have the libraries installed; but

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

should fix that; unfortunately the dependency list in the `google-chrome` package isn't complete, so you'll probably need to install

```
sudo apt-get install libexif12:amd64 libpulse0:amd64
```

to get Chrome running properly.

[Cross-grading](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading) an `i386` userspace to `amd64` is also possible, but it's far more complicated and risky.

Comment: What is "cross-grading"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha it's switching architectures without reinstalling – a sort of upgrade where software isn't upgraded! See https://wiki.debian.org/CrossGrading for details.

Comment: Oh, I see. Converting an `i386` installation to `amd64`, for example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha exactly, a.k.a. "cross-grading an `i386` userspace to `amd64`" ;-). I'll update my answer to include the link.

Comment: @StephenKitt Didint work as spected, edited the question to add the response

Comment: @LeoArmentano the package provided by Google is missing some dependency information, see my edit.

Comment: Consider completely removing your current chrome package and reinstalling it, perhaps also using the actual Debian packages.

Comment: My Google Chrome AMD 64 installation succeeds but when I run it I get `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`